# Disable auto fill mode in noweb-mode

Tags: emacs, autofill

Please for the love of god how can I make Emacs stop auto-filling? I use `visual-line-mode`, I do not want auto fill. I can turn it off with `M-x auto-fill-mode RET` but in Noweb mode it gets turned back on when I move into a code chunk and back out again. Please, I just want to globally turn of auto fill mode, it's driving me crazy.

I've tried

```
(auto-fill-mode 0)
```

and a bunch of crazy things like

```
(add-hook 'Rnw-mode-hook '(lambda () (auto-fill-mode 0)))
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook '(lambda () (auto-fill-mode 0)))
```

But nothing seems to work. Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of adding further hooks to your system, you should check if you could remove some to disable auto-fill.

If you see [noweb-mode's source code](ftp://www.eecs.harvard.edu/pub/nr/noweb/src/elisp/noweb-mode.el), around line 211 you find this chunk:

```
(add-hook 'noweb-select-doc-mode-hook 'noweb-auto-fill-doc-mode)
(add-hook 'noweb-select-code-mode-hook 'noweb-auto-fill-code-mode)
```

To disable auto filling, put the following one or two lines in your dotemacs (depending on whether you want to disable auto-fill in both code and documentation).

```
(remove-hook 'noweb-select-doc-mode-hook 'noweb-auto-fill-doc-mode)
(remove-hook 'noweb-select-code-mode-hook 'noweb-auto-fill-code-mode)
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, I worked out a hack that does the trick:

```
(setq auto-fill-mode -1)
(setq-default fill-column 99999)
(setq fill-column 99999)
```

If I can't turn off auto-fill mode, at least I can make it harmless by setting it to fill only in column 99999. I'll be annoyed if I type a paragraph with more than 99999 characters, but if that happens I'll have bigger things to worry about...

Answer (score 3):

If you look at `simple.el`, at the very top `text-mode-hook` is defined, which is ultimately responsible for turning on this abomination (or at least, it was for me).

To get to simple.el and look for yourself: (C-h f, `auto-fill-mode`, click / follow simple.el link)

To disable, M-x customize-variable text-mode-hook

[Screen shot](http://screencast.com/t/GizgzTDzn)

Uncheck turn-on-auto-fill. Be sure to click "Save for future sessions" at the top.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but what if you want to keep `auto-fill-mode` by default in `text-mode` and its derivaites, but just disable it in some specific modes, like `noweb-mode` or `latex-mode`?