# How can I disable auto-fill mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, word-wrap, org-mode

Today I got my new PC ([Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7), 32 bit) and installed [Vincelt Goulets Emacs](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/windows/). The only other thing I did was updating [Org-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode).

Now, I am stuck with `auto-fill-mode` on every time I start Emacs new, which I hate. I would like to turn `auto-fill-mode` off, for now and forever. I even deleted my *.emacs* file, but `auto-fill-mode` was still turned on.

The only solution that worked was (a) [a nasty workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567431/289572) or (b) always typing `M-x auto-fill-mode` every time I start Emacs anew.

Is there a solution?

---

To be clear, the only thing the current .emacs file contains is:  `'(inhibit-startup-screen t)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add to your `.emacs`,

```
(auto-fill-mode -1)
```

If there are hooks for specific modes, you will need to zap those as well.  My suspicion is that you do not actually have auto-fill-mode on by default in all modes, but with the information you have supplied, at least this should be a starting point.

A reasonable safeguard would be to also disable auto-fill mode from `text-mode-hook':

```
(remove-hook 'text-mode-hook #'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

You may need something similar for other modes as well.

Comment: The `text-mode-hook` made the trick. Unfortunately just turning `auto-fill-mode` off did not work. So the Vincent Goulet emacs automatically loads `auto-fill` via `text-mode`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also modify this by using `M-x customize-variable`, `text-mode-hook`. Uncheck it, be sure to click "save for future sessions".

Comment: These didn't help with Aquamacs :( However, the following worked with Aquamacs  : `(remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'auto-detect-wrap)` (Note that might have other effects with setting automatically word-wrap?)

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that he has not made fundamental changes, you have several paths:

You can just turn off the mode globally in your `.emacs` file:

```
(turn-off-auto-fill)
;; ...or (auto-fill-mode -1)
```

Since Emacs of that vintage also turns on auto-fill for `text-mode`, add:

```
(remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

That should account for all the default places, but check the major mode hooks if you have other modes enabling this automatically.

Comment: I added both of these to my ~/.emacs (I'm using Aquamacs) and they do not work, at least with my setup.

Comment: Same problem as the person above. Maybe it's Aquamacs specific

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to keep it turned-on in most `text-mode` while disable `auto-fill` in specific modes, e.g. `org-mode` in my case, you could use the following:

```
;; turn on auto-fill for text-mode
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
;; turn off auto-fill for org-mode
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill)
```