# How can I adjust Emacs "Spc" mode?

Tags: emacs

I have a window whose mode line at the bottom says "(Text Spc Fill)", probably as a default for *.txt filenames.  "Spc" seems to be a minor mode which attempts to preserve English text by, for example, collapsing two spaces to one after a word is removed.  However, I don't want that in this buffer.

So, how can I turn off this minor mode?

I don't know the actual name of the mode.  I tried `M-x spc-mode` and `M-x space-mode`, and I looked through a few help pages.

More generally, is there an easy way to get the list of modes which are active in the current buffer?  Or to find out about a mode given its mode-line abbreviation?  (These can be unpredictable; for example, `M-x visual-line-mode` corresponds to `(WordWrap)`.)

This is Aquamacs, Emacs version 23.3.50.1.

Comment: edited answer..left a bit out!

Comment: Not sure about Aquamacs, but Emacs 24.3 has a command `describe-minor-mode-from-indicator`

Comment: `C-h m` shows that this is a minor mode called Smart-Spacing (apparently specific to Aquamacs).  So `M-x smart-spacing-mode` turns it off.

Comment: And `describe-minor-mode-from-indicator` works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your second question, the command `describe-mode` (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>) will list

- your major mode, along with
- some documentation (usually including keybindings), and
- all of the minor modes that are active

You might be surprised how many minor modes are active in a typical setup.  Not all active modes have an "indicator."

Comment: @tripleee, thanks -- I've also noticed that this indicator is called a "lighter" in the documentation.  The `lighter` argument to `define-minor-mode` is used to set it.

Answer (score 0):

in your .emacs file add the line

```
  (remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9879056/1675954)

Comment: I think this refers to the `Fill` in the modeline, not the `Spc` the OP is talking about.

Comment: spc just breaks lines when appropriate in auto fill mode

Comment: Are you sure? I never have seen this "Spc" and I use auto-fill all the time for that effect.

Comment: yep i'm sure, http://www.linux-france.org/article/appli/emacs/manuel/html/c2305.html

Comment: Auto-fill puts "Fill" in the modeline, not "Spc", which is what we're asking about. I get "Fill"/auto-fill-mode. Not "Spc" and whatever mode it's associated with.

Comment: 24.3, but I don't think auto-fill by itself puts "Spc" in the modeline in any version. Does it?

Comment: i think this is actually a python added hook

Comment: The OP believes this default is assigned to files named *.txt, which would make Python an unlikely culprit.

Comment: Good to know in case I want to remove this problem in future, thanks @Rachel.